# UUID.randomUUID().toString() on update or reinstallation

Tags: android, uuid

It say that "UUIDs can be generated on first run, saved to a file and then checked at any time to uniquely identify installations."

But when I reinstall my app by connecting my device on USB, transfer the apk and install it on the file explorator by clicking on the file.apk. The UUID doesn't change why ?

And does it change on PlayStore update, or manually uninstallation and reinstallation ?

EDIT: Store the UUID:

```
public class Installation {
    private static String sID = null;
    private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

    public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
        if (sID == null) {
            File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
            try {
                if (!installation.exists())
                    writeInstallationFile(installation);
                sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return sID;
    }

    private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        f.readFully(bytes);
        f.close();
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        out.write(id.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Catch it from the fragment:

```
idApplication = Installation.id(getActivity());
```

Comment: "when I reinstall my app" -- was the app manually uninstalled? Or were you just upgrading/replacing the existing installation?

Comment: Unless you wipe the app's data (e.g. by uninstalling the app) I wouldn't expect the saved UUID to disappear. It would be pretty bad if updating an app wiped the app's data.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't uninstalled the app, I just clicked on the apk file it says "insall an update..." and I tap on install

Comment: @Michael So you mean that an update keep all data, so sqlite, uuid and others ?

Comment: "So you mean that an update keep all data, so sqlite, uuid and others ?" -- yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare To be sure, if I uninstall the app my UUID gonna be erased ? And I'm gonna take a new after a fresh installation

Comment: "if I uninstall the app my UUID gonna be erased ?" -- if you have the UUID on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't store the UUID.randomUUID().toString(), I'm just calling it

Comment: Then you did not follow the instructions. "UUIDs can be generated on first run, **saved to a file**, and then checked at any time to uniquely identify installations" (emphasis added).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks I just edited my question I stored the UUID

Comment: @CommonsWare It was true I haven't see that the UUID was changing, now with this code, the UUID still stored :) thanks